# NHibernate 5.1 ManyToOne - delete orphan not working as expected

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-one, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I have following entities:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public Passport Passport {get;set;}
}

public class Passport {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public String PassportNo {get;set;}
    // ... other properties
}
```

and following mapping (for Person):

```
ManyToOne(x => x.Passport, m =>
    {
        m.Column("PassportId");
        m.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
        m.Unique(true);
        m.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
    });
```

DB schema:

```
Table Person:

Id | Name | PassportId

Table Passport:

Id | PassportNo | other props.
```

As we can see, `Person` has it's passport, but passport has no idea about its owner, which is behaviour I want. There are 2 more assumptions:

- `Person` can have only 1 passport at a time
- `Passport` can NOT exists without person

Problem is, when I assign new `Passport` to a `Person`, the old `Passport` remains in DB.

```
person.Passport = new Passport() { PassportNo = "AB 123456" };
// ...
session.Flush();
session.Commit();
```

SQL queries that are generated are INSERT and UPDATE (inserts new `Passport`, and updates `Person` with new `Passport`) - **however there is no DELETE on orphaned, old passport**.

The workaround I found is to set current `Passport` to `null`, call `session.Flush()`, and assign new `Passport`, like this:

```
person.Passport = null;
session.Flush();
person.Passport = new Passport() { PassportNo = "AB 123456" };
// ...
session.Flush();
session.Commit();
```

however IMO it is a hacky solution.

So, summing it up:

- am I missing something in my mapping?
- is above behaviour a bug in NH?
- can it be solved without hacky `Flush()`?

Comment: Are the cascade settings correct? I found this (http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html) and it looks like `Remove` is an option rather than `DeleteOrphan`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long searching for solution, I found that there is a `Join` mapping, which perfectly fits above scenario.

Hope it helps someone.

More info here:
http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-join.html